# Menu option "Select startup disk on desktop" greyed out when Finder window is active

Tags: macos, finder

Previous OS X versions allowed one to select the startup disk using Cmd-Shift-Up when on the Desktop, or "from" any Finder window. In 10.9.4 this works only from the Desktop. When a Finder window is active, the menu item does appear when holding down Shift, but is greyed out.
The startup disk *is* visible on the Desktop, per Finder preferences.
Any ideas? I can make a workaround using Keyboard Maestro or the likes, but..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a workaround using KeyboardMaestro: only in Finder, on hotkey (⌘⇧↑), execute AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    select window of desktop
    set selection to item 1 of desktop
end tell
```

Weirdly enough it doesn't *show* that it is selected, but Cmd-down opens its window.